# How to use KEY_INT_RUNTIME_DEPTH_FRAMERATE

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I want to know if I can use the latest API config property `KEY_INT_RUNTIME_DEPTH_FRAMERATE` to slow down the sampling of `xyzij` data. i.e. reduce how many point clouds the device picks up per second.

a) Is this is the right way to go about it?

b) If so, do I set this value as shown here (after I enable Depth config):  `mConfig.putInt(TangoConfig.KEY_INT_RUNTIME_DEPTH_FRAMERATE, 1)`

c) Other options to control the sampling speed?

Answer (score 0):

To use the runtime config, you could query the runtime config object after connected to the service. For example, after the service connection call, call this:

`mRuntimeConfig = mTango.getConfig(TangoConfig.CONFIG_TYPE_RUNTIME);`

After querying the runtime config, you should be able to set the KEY_INT_RUNTIME_DEPTH_FRAMERATE as long as the Tango Service is connected.

`mRuntimeConfig.putDouble(TangoConfig.KEY_INT_RUNTIME_DEPTH_FRAMERATE, 1.0)`

But please note that the framerate on the Tango tablet is 0~5 hz (inclusive) at the moment.